# Is it efficient to create a new column in SQL Server and find only matching data in the new column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am wondering if the following process is efficient, or if there is a better way to go about this:

Table consists of 4 relevant columns:

- Id
- Date of Birth (1984-03-19)
- First Name (John)
- Last Name (Doe)

I want to concatenate these columns to create '1984-03-19 John Doe' as a new column. Then I want to take a list of values (there is a .csv file containing DOB, First, Last name) in this format and only pull the **Id** from the table when there is a match.

The table has millions of rows, so I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to write this query.

This is for an ad hoc request.

Comment: Why would you *want* to do that?

Comment: I pity the John Does born on the same day.

Comment: @Larnu - I have a list of about 1k values in this concatenated format. I'm trying to find their "Id" value from a table. The only fields to comapre are Dob, First, and Last Name.

Comment: If you want to search the table, then pass the values for each column: `WHERE Firstname = 'John' AND LastName = 'Doe' AND DoB = '19870319'` doing something like `WHERE FirstName + LastName + DoB = ...`  is going to give a conversion error, and if you do `CONVERT` `DoB` it's not going to be a SARGable query *due to the `CONVERT` and the concatenation). If the query is slow, it's likely due to poor, or lack of, indexing,

Comment: Are you saying that you already have a different table that has 'DOB First Last' as a field that you are trying to compare with?  If so, you can do what you describe or perhaps I'd prefer the opposite -- split the other field into DOB, first, last and then do DOB=DOB, first=first, last=last.

Comment: @avery_larry -- Yep, exactly.

Comment: Is this a one-off? Or will you need to do this once an hour for many rows? It matters because creating columns and indexing them is a costly operation, and may take more time than just doing a simple unindexed query just once.  Please [edit] your question to tell us how often you need to do this.

Comment: @O.Jones This is a one-off. Updated the question per your recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the CSV file into a table.  Let's call it CSV.

We'll call your original table `t`.

Then you want a simple `JOIN`:

```
select t.id
from csv join
     t
     on t.firstname = csv.firstname and
        t.lastname = csv.lastname and
        t.dob = csv.dob;
```

Voila!  Done.  No concatenation.

For performance, you want an index on `t(firstname, lastname, dob)` with the columns in any order.

Comment: Thank you very much. Joining on these values instead of creating a new key to search through, and the the index on `t(firstname, lastname, dob)` is what I need to learn more about from a performance perspective.